# SpringBoot with Spring-Data-JPA: ArrayList/JSON object is repopulating each time request is made

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating this REST API in SpringBoot.  I am using Spring-Data-JPA to map my object called Site with a MySql database.
In a Controller I have set a RequestMapping Annotation to return a list of Site Object from the database. This method in the controller is calling another method (getItinerary) from a Service Bean.  I have set the Scope of the service to "prototype" (Initially it was set to default value of Singleton).

The problem is each time I am hitting the link (localhost:8080/getItinerary) the returned Json is repopulating the list along with the data that was previously returned.  I want to return new List of Sites every time i hit the link.

Here are my codes:

AlternateTravelPlan.java (My Service Bean)

```
package...

import...



@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class AlternateTravelPlan {

@Autowired
TravelPlanRepo travelPlanRepo;


ArrayList<Site> siteList = new ArrayList<>;

public List<Site> getItinerary() {


    //Enhance For Loop to fetch Site List from Database
    for (Site site : travelPlanRepo.findAll()) {
        siteList.add(site);
    }
    return siteList;
}
}
```

TravelPlanRepo.java

```
package...
import...

import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface TravelPlanRepo extends JpaRepository<Site, Integer>{

}
```

ItineraryController.java

```
import....

@RestController
public class ItineraryController{


@Autowired 
AlternateTravelPlan alternateTravelPlan;

@Autowired
TravelPlanRepo travelPlanRepo;

@RequestMapping("/getItinerary")
public List<Site> getItinerary(){
    return alternateTravelPlan.getItinerary();

}

}
```

I have another POJO called Site that is map with the database.  I'm not putting the codes from this class because it's irrelevant in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your siteList variable has global scope, so it's adding new items to the collection it already has every time you call getItinerary(). You should either make siteList a variable that's locally scoped within the getItinerary method, clear it each time the method is called, or create a new instance each time the method is called. E.g.:

```
 package...

 import...



 @Service
 @Scope("prototype")
 public class AlternateTravelPlan {


 private TravelPlanRepo travelPlanRepo;

 //By autowiring constructors we avoid NPEs...
 @Autowired
 public AlternativeTravelPlan(TravelPlanRepo travelPlanRepo){
      this.travelPlanRepo = travelPlanRepo;
 }

 public List<Site> getItinerary() {

      List siteList = new ArrayList();
      //Enhance For Loop to fetch Site List from Database
      for (Site site : travelPlanRepo.findAll()) {
           siteList.add(site);
      }
      return siteList;
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much Bill.  It solved the problem. It was such a simple thing that went unnoticed by me.  Thanks for clarifying this for me.

I have another question for you.  I am having difficulty to understand the scope of the service.  Even if i don't set the scope to prototype, i am getting the result just fine.  But isn't doesn't the prototype scope allow new instance of AlternatitveTravelPlan to be created with each request?  How come when i replace it with the default value of Singleton.  It still works? @Bill-Horvath

Comment: You're very welcome! Since it solved your problem, I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer or voted it up here on the SE platform.

Comment: As to your question about scope, you're correct that setting the scope to prototype means a new instance of AlternativeTravelPlan will be created whenever it's instantiated. However, TravelPlanRepo is a singleton (by default), so your new AlternativeTravelPlan instances are all using the same TravelPlanRepo instance. As long as the data repository hasn't changed, you'll get the same results from getItinerary() from all of your AlternativeTravelPlans instances no matter how many you create.

Comment: thanks a lot Bill..I have already up voted your answer. It's saying as my reputation is below 15, it's not displaying it publicly.  However I clicked the tick mark, I believe this means I have accepted your answer as solution.  Thanks a lot again.